# How to pass parameters panelgroup - binding, JSF

Tags: jsf, binding

I have a `datatable` that reads registers from a database.
In the `datatable` I have a `panelgroup` that is populated by binding
My problem is that I can not pass a parameter. I want to pass a value from the `datatable` variable, in that case preg, on each row I want to know the value of the register read to populate the `panelgroup`.

If I display the value it works fine for each row: `#{preg.idpreg}`

```
<h:dataTable var="preg"  value="#{Pregbacking.list(Pregbacking.idenq)}">
    <h:column>
        #{preg.idpreg}
        <h:panelGroup binding="#{Pregbacking.dynamicDataTableGroup(preg.idpreg)}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That should work just find but I believe that you need to make sure you are using a modern servlet spec (v3 I think).  Use the latest Glassfish or Tomcat app server.

Comment: I am using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 (build 22).

Comment: If I "fix" the parameter i works, for exemple:

Comment: <h:panelGroup binding="#{Pregbacking.dynamicDataTableGroup(5)}"/>, but the problem i that the value of the datatable var is not passed when it is called the binding.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what would be wrong then.  We're doing the exact same thing in our project and it works perfect.